# 500 internal server error with wordpress

Tags: errors

I always get 500 internal server error when I try to access my wordpress website, but if I put a php.ini (memory-limit:60MB) file in the WP-ADMIN folder, then I can access the site fine., but phpmyadmin doesn't work anymore with the following error:

```
 Fatal error: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]:         Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: ) in  /libraries/session.inc.php on line 83
```

I have another wordpress site with the same server configuration (LNMP), and it doesn't have this problem.

Anyone know why I need that php.ini in the WP-ADMIN or why it is causing 500 error.

Thank you.

The wordpress install that have this problem is running the latest version 3.9.1.

Comment: Is your site hosted on wordpress.com?

Comment: @Pieter Goosen No, its on VPS (LNMP stack)

Comment: Then please do not use the wordpress.com tag, as these questions are off topic